# discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "createvc" is not found

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to add a function to a discord bot that allows me to add voice channels to a discord server
the current code for this function looks like this.

```
@commands.command(name='createvc')
async def makevc(self, ctx: commands.context, channelName):
    guild = client.get_guild(id)
    guild.create_voice_channel(name=channelName)
    pass
```

I have tried comparing the command to other commands in the bot, and I have tried multiple different things instead of @commands but I always get the exact same error when I try to use the command from discord.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your bot command to be invoked through different statements you can define a list of **`aliases`** as an additional parameter for the command decorator.

```
@commands.command(aliases = ["createvc"])
```

Answer (score 0):

From the information that I can get from your question, your command definition isn't in a Cog, so you should use `bot.command()` instead of `commands.command()`.

So you should do:

```
@bot.command(name='createvc')
async def makevc(self, ctx: commands.context, channelName):
    guild = client.get_guild(id)
    guild.create_voice_channel(name=channelName)
    pass
```

instead of

```
@commands.command(name='createvc')
async def makevc(ctx: commands.context, channelName):
    guild = client.get_guild(733719693894090772)
    await guild.create_voice_channel(name=channelName)
    pass
```